# Rewrite Promise-based code with async\await

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm trying to rewrite this `Promise`-based code using `async` \ `await`:

```
public loadData(id: string): void {
    this.loadDataAsync()
        .then((data: any): void => {
             // Do something with data
        })
        .catch((ex): void => {
             // Do something with ex
        });
}

public loadDataAsync(): Promise<any> {
    // return Promise somehow
}
```

The rewritten code I have so far is:

```
public loadData(id: string): void {
    let data: any;

    try {
        data = await this.loadDataAsync();
    } catch(ex) {
         // Do something with ex
    }

    // Do something with data
}

public async loadDataAsync(): Promise<any> {
    // return Promise somehow
}
```

The problem is that I have to make `loadData()` method `async` since it has await in its body. Then, I have to return some `Promise` from it, since `async` methods must return  a `Promise`. But I need to maintain the API of `loadData()` method and return `void`.

How can I achieve this? How do you break a never ending need for making a method as `async` when somewhere deep inside inner calls you're calling an `async` method?

Comment: async methods automatically return a promise. You return whatever you want inside the async method, that value will be used for the callbacks, meaning what you return isn't what actually gets returned by the function.

Comment: `public async loadDataAsync(): Promise<any> {` doesn't make sense. Either use `public async loadDataAsync(): any {` or `public loadDataAsync(): Promise<any> {` but not both `async` and `Promise<any>`

Comment: @PatrickEvans: `async` methods implicitly return a `Promise` and TypeScript requires you to specify so for such method signatures. That's what I've meant by `I have to return some Promise from it, since async methods must return a Promise.`

Comment: @599644: You can't specify `any` as a return value type of an `async` method in TS. Check [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=async%20function%20f()%3A%20any%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%201%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ideally if you can change the function declaration, just add the `async` keyword to `loadData` and use `await` inside like so:

```
public async loadData(id: string): void {
    let data: any;

    try {
        data = await this.loadDataAsync();
    } catch(ex) {
         // Do something with ex
    }
}
```

If you are unable to change the `loadData` function declaration, then you can just create an anonymous `async` function inside, and then call `await` within the anonymous function like so:

```
public loadData(id: string): void {
    let data: any;

    try {
        data = (async () => { return await this.loadDataAsync() })();
    } catch(ex) {
         // Do something with ex
    }
}

public async loadDataAsync(): Promise<any> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        // Logic goes here
        resolve(data);
    });
}
```

Whenever you use the `await` keyword, the surrounding function must be marked as `async`.

---

As was pointed out by the OP in the comments, in TypeScript it is best practice to mark the promise returning method with `async` as well (see the `loadDataAsync` function above), as this ensures the return type is always a promise. More info on that found here:

[TypeScript Async / Await Tutorial](https://blog.bitsrc.io/keep-your-promises-in-typescript-using-async-await-7bdc57041308)

Comment: Regarding your statement `You only use Async when you call Await, not on the promise method.` Could you explain why there is a TS Lint [rule](https://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/promise-function-async/) `promise-function-async` which makes sure all methods returning a `Promise` must be `async`? From the existence of this rule and its rationale, one might believe marking all `Promise`-returning methods with `async` is a good practice.

Comment: @AlexanderAbakumov thanks for pointing that out, I updated my answer to reflect that point!